# sass function using only the second argument

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

sass 
I want to use that function

```
@function baseFontSize($vw : .05vw, $coef : 1){
    $return : calc((10px + #{$vw}) * #{$coef});
    @return $return;
}
```

I call it in that way

```
font-size: baseFontSize();
or
font-size: baseFontSize(1vw);
or
font-size: baseFontSize(1vw, 1.2);
```

but what if I want to keep the first argument as is and set only the second one ?

```
font-size: baseFontSize(default, 1.2);  ?
```

how can I do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about this.

```
@function baseFontSize($vw : .05vw, $coef : 1) {
  @if ($vw == ''){
    $vw : 0.5vw;
  }
  @if ($coef=='') {
    $coef: 1;
  }
  $return : calc((10px + #{$vw}) * #{$coef});
  @return $return;
}


.test1{
  font-size: baseFontSize();
}
.test2{
  font-size: baseFontSize( '',1.5 );
}
.test3{
  font-size: baseFontSize( .08vw,'' );
}
```